# How to disable tab auto-complete "camera flash" for MacOS terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

Whenever I use the tab auto-complete feature in the default terminal for MacOS, there is a visual effect much like a **camera flash** that illuminates the terminal window for a fraction of a second. It is fairly distracting, and I would like to disable it. I've checked the preferences, but couldn't find a relevant option. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: I should specify, it only happens when nothing has been typed in but a path is expected.

For example, typing "cd " and hitting tab will produce a camera flash, whereas "cd Downlo" and hitting tab will not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like the "visual bell" that's normally used when the Terminal receives a BELL character, but the sound is muted. If that's it, you can change it with Terminal menu > Preferences -> Profiles section -> Advanced tab -> uncheck the Visual Bell option.

BTW, this also disables that flash for anything else that would normally trigger a Terminal bell sound. You can trigger this yourself with the command `printf '\a'` (the `\a` translates to the "alert" or BELL character).

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly the option I was looking for. Appreciate the wider insights into the Terminal bell as well.